# If X/A is homeomorphic to Y/B and A is homeomorphic to B, is it true that X is homeomorphic to Y?

Tags: general-topology

Something I've used in a couple of exercises without proof; intuitively it seems true but I'm not sure how to go about proving or disproving it.
If it isn't true in general does it hold under any constraints that mean it can still be useful?
Here I mean X and Y are topological spaces and A and B are subspaces of X and Y respectively, with the subspace topology, and X/A and Y/B are quotient spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Let $X$ be two disjoint circles, $A$ two points (one on each circle). Let $Y$ be an interval with a circle kissing it in the middle, $B$ the two end points of the interval. Then $X/A$ and $Y/B$ are both two kissing circles.

[image]

Here's anotherr example where $X$ is a T shape and $A,B,Y$ are intervals - with the added bonus that the induced *pointed* spaces are also homeomorphic (i.e., the red dots "lie in the same place" of the quotients on the right):

[image]